# Issue at dividing bootstrap grid system according to the PSD

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

For a responsive website development I am using twitter bootstrap framework. According to the psd total width of the container is 980px, left-block width is 607px right-block width 373px.

If I use `col-md-8` & `col-md-4` the following width can't be achieved. So is there any poosibility to overcome it? Or Should I ask the designer to design according to the grid system (12 column) layout

http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/h36u8foc/[image]

Comment: Pixel-perfect design shouldn't be something you should try to attain in any responsive layouts. I work with people who still do 960 grids and there is an education process to get them up to speed with today's standards. I usually just take their layout and make it look as close as possible. BTW 7 and 5 is closer than 8 and 4.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use grid for your website, ask the designer to design with grids, because it will be very hard for you to use a "semi-grid" layout.

But i think your container should be 960px instead of 980px because we can divide 960 by 2 and 3 but not 980px.

12 cols on 960 layout : 12 cols of 80px

12 cols on 980 layout : 12 cols of 81.666666667px

Comment: now the problem is,  designer needs the width to the left and right block should be as per his design.   now the question is  whether his requirement is feasible or not by bootstrap or any other framework ?

Comment: There is nothing that prevent to use a framework like bootstrap but you will set "manually" the width of this 2 blocks.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but am expecting that designer has to change his way of designing  (something stuff like that)..

Answer (score 0):

You can't with Bootstrap standard grid. This is a limit of all Grid Framework, based on columns layout.

A possible solution is provided in this [updated example](http://jsfiddle.net/h36u8foc/2/):

I added a "custom-grid" class to container div, in order to limit effect on customization to only this particular region.

Then, I added the following override rules for both column. With this % values, *difference respect your desired result is limited in 1px*.

```
.custom-grid .left-block
{
    width:62%
}

.custom-grid .right-block
{
    width:38%;
}
```

Instead, if you want to use Bootstrap standard, you must ask your designer to re-design layout based on columns.

Anyway, I suggest this other Grid System, called [**PocketGrid**](http://arnaudleray.github.io/pocketgrid/). I already used it in commercial solutions, and using % instead of cols, lets you total customization power.